# Change checkbox depending on value in data global attribute

Tags: checkbox, attributes

I am trying to change/disable a checkbox based on the `data-count` global attribute set in the `td` at the right of the checkbox.

```
data-count = 0 -> checkbox should be disabled
data-count > 0 -> checkbox should be checked
```

```js
$('td.day').each(function() {           
    // set checkbox disable
    if ($(this).attr('data-count') == 0) {
            
    } else {
        // set checkbox checked
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <table id="mytable">
      <thead>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
      </thead>
      
      <tbody>
        <tr id="rw1">
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" /></td>
          <td class="day data-count="0">10</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" /></td>
          <td class="day data-count="2">11</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr id="rw2">
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" /></td>
          <td class="day data-count="1"">20</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" /></td>
          <td class="day data-count="0">21</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check/uncheck checkboxes via call to `.prop('checked', value)`
You can query previous element via `.prev`

```
$('td.day').each(function() {           
    if ($(this).attr('data-count') == 0) {  
        // set checkbox UNCHECKED
        $(this).prev().find('input').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        // set checkbox CHECKED
        $(this).prev().find('input').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Working example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PJBaLM)